# Back button on keyboard is acting like phone back key, how to distinguish them?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I'm writing my first small app on Xamarin Android. I noticed that my app sometimes is suddenly closing, I found that it's closing when I'm holding back button on keyboard to delete text in text field.

I have this code that is supposed to make press back button twice to exit app:

```
bool doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (myWebView != null)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && myWebView.CanGoBack())
        {
            myWebView.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
                Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
                return false;
            }

            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Press back again to exit app", ToastLength.Short).Show();

            new Handler().PostDelayed(() => {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But apperently it's not reacting to phone's 'back' button, but also to 'back' on keyboard.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it with adding next code into first **if** statement

```
if (myWebView != null && e.Flags != (Android.Views.KeyEventFlags.KeepTouchMode | Android.Views.KeyEventFlags.SoftKeyboard))
```

I still wonder if this is right way to fix my problem.